# Lenovo T495 - Opensuse Tumbleweed - USB does not work when on battery

Tags: linux, usb, battery

I have a Lenovo T495 and it works fine when on mains.  However when on battery, USB devices (flashdrives, hdds, etc) are not detected.  Plug in the mains, and they are detected fine.  Running kernel 5.6.11-1.

Within tlp.conf i have the following set

USB_AUTOSUSPEND=0

And there is nothing in the BIOS to suggest power is disabled whilst on battery.

Any ideas please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the T495 this is indeed down to TLP, disabling TLP completely and rebooting caused USB devices to work on battery alone.

For me the fix was to run lspci and find the AMD USB controllers.

```
06:00.3 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven USB 3.1
06:00.4 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven USB 3.1
```

Then add them to the RUNTIME_PM_BLACKLIST in /etc/tlp.conf

```
RUNTIME_PM_BLACKLIST="06:00.3 06:00.4"
```

Reboot - USB works on battery whilst TLP is still functional.